# Remove strictly strong/bold text tag from html via Jquery

Tags: jquery

currently having a slight problem with respect to removing strong tags using jquery.

I want to retain the text between the strong tags, so eg:
before:

```
<strong>This is a text</strong>
```

After:

```
this is a text
```

and Code:

```
    $("div.row.ordertype").each(function(){
           if(($(this).text()).length>0){
            console.log($(this).html());
            var test = $("<strong>","<strong />").contents().unwrap();
            console.log(test);
           }    
    })
```

any ideas

Answer (score 3):

Use below jQuery

```
$('strong').contents().unwrap();
```

For faster performance, always use below:

```
var strong = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');
while(strong.length) {
    var parent = strong[0].parentNode;
    while( strong[0].firstChild ) {
        parent.insertBefore(strong[0].firstChild, strong[0]);
    }
     parent.removeChild(strong[0]);
}
```

This will more faster than any jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```js
$("strong").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>This is a text</strong>
```

The selector `$("<strong>","<strong />")` creates new elements, it doesn't select elements

Comment: This has worked. Many thanks. Dont know why i been voted down tho because the question contains all the required info :/